# How to Rock Paper Scissors game with images in PHP and HTML

Tags: php, html, image, format

first page-im using radio buttons..so the user will click
rock for example and the computer will play paper but i want it
to be using images.. i just started coding and so very lost

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
     <title>Rock Paper Scissors Game</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="rps3.php" method="post">
<h1> Rock Paper Scissors Game</h1>
    <p>Your Choice:</p>
    <p>Rock<input type="radio" value="rock" name="playerthrows"  />
       Paper<input type="radio" value="paper" name="playerthrows"  />
       Scissors<input type="radio" value="scissors" name="playerthrows" />
    </p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Play"></p>



</form>

</body>
</html>
```

second page- this is how i thought the php would look...
I dont know how to attatch images + this code is not working. The output would like this > You picked: scissors & The computer picked: rock, paper, scissors or> Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in /home/game/public_html/rps3.php on line 20
You picked: paper
&
The computer picked:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
     <title>Rock Paper Scissors Game</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Rock Paper Scissors Game</h1>

<?php
    if($_POST['playerthrows']){

}

    else if(!$_POST['playerthrows']){

}
        $playerthrows = $_POST['playerthrows'];
        $Choosefrom= array('rock, paper, scissors');
        $Choice= rand(0,2);
        $Computer=$Choosefrom[$Choice];

    echo 'You picked: '.$playerthrows.'';
    echo '<br />&<br />';
    echo 'The computer picked: '. $Computer .'';

    if($playerthrows == $Computer){
    }
    if ($playerthrows == $Computer){
    echo ' Draw  ';
    }
    else if($playerthrows == 'rock ' && $Computer == 'scissors'){
    echo 'You Win!';
}
    else if($playerthrows == 'rock' && $Computer == 'paper'){
    echo  'You Lose! ';
}
    else if($playerthrows == 'scissors' && $Computer == 'rock'){
    echo  ' You Lose! ';
}
    else if($playerthrows == 'scissors' && $Computer == 'paper'){
    echo ' You Win!' ;
}
    else if($playerthrows == 'paper' && $Computer == 'rock'){
    echo 'You Win!';
}
    else if($playerthrows == 'paper' && $Computer == 'scissors'){
    echo 'You Lose!' ;
}

?>      


</body>
```

I know these mistakes are probably really noob level but it'd be appreciated if any one can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is becauese you $Choosefrom variable have only one element, - string that contains comas. You should replace it with:

```
$Choosefrom= array('rock', 'paper', 'scissors');
```

If you want to use images, than the best way for you is just to put [< img>](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp) with pictures of rock paper or scissors, instead of captions.
There is a ways to make it all more plausable, but you will need to learn CSS

Comment: so instead of 'rock' '<img src="rock.png" alt="rock" >'

Comment: yes, various approaches may be used if you want to customize view of the radio inputs, but that's totally another question, you can find plenty of answers https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=custom+radio+button, but for now simply putting image at the right place will be good task for you to learn CSS